# Issue with default dates on AngularJS form with moment.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, momentjs

I'm using AngularJS with moment.js. Ehen I load the following code it always sets today as the default date in the date picker control on the webpage. I want this to be `NULL` by default, is this possible? It seems that loading moment.js is causing this to happen.

```js
.config(function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
        return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    };
})
```

```html
<label>Date of Birth</label>
<md-datepicker ng-model="user.Date_Of_Birth"></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions Peter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [md-datepicker documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) `ng-model` is a required attribute with type of `date`. So no, you can't have a default value wich is `null`, it must be an type of `date`:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="birthday"></md-datepicker>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdz2841u/) of what you try to approach (with an default date). [This invalide fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n8vpqoz/1/) uses `null` as default date -> so the datepicker shows `invalide date` this time.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myDate = new moment()._d
}).config(function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
        return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    };
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't load moment.js then its blank by default but I need moment.js to change the format of dates to UK.

Comment: @PeterMoss It's working as expected. I added a working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/fdz2841u/ and one with `null` as default date value -> http://jsfiddle.net/4n8vpqoz/1/ Please give more information about your problem.

Comment: Hi, Here's what I want to happen - http://codepen.io/petemossuk/pen/peEPmP but when I add uncomment the code to use moment.js it sets the default date as today every time the page loads when I need it to be null/blank by default so the user HAS to enter/select the date themselves.

Comment: @PeterMoss Looks like a bug behavior to me. Due to the documentation a `ng-model` value which is not a `date` is invalide. It's a bug, not a feature. Please create a bug report @github https://github.com/angular/material & init your datepicker with an object of the type `date`. The behavior of `null` as default date is not supported by `md-datepicker` -> you cant achieve that. You may going to create an custom directive for your handling.

Comment: @PeterMoss why do you need a non preselected datepicker btw? This is something unusual in web applications.

Comment: I wanted the user to select a date so it needed to be blank by default, simple requirement in my eyes :) I managed to get around it by changing the locateprovider to       return !date ? '' : moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'); The issue I have now, and appears without this code too is that if you manual type in or change a preselected date then it gives you a very random date - as per this - http://codepen.io/petemossuk/pen/mRNKpv

Comment: your example didn't work as I needed it too. I found the answer on an angular page where they said it was a bug, however there are still issues when it used in certain scenarios. If your able to answer then please let me know.

Comment: As I said: its a bug not a feature. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds the above solution a bit inadequate please consider the alternative:

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date" placeholder="...">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
             <mat-datepicker #dp 
                                  startView="year"
                                  (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                                  (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
             </mat-datepicker>
    </div>
```

**Angular**

```
    date = new FormControl(); //Initialize the date without moment

    chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
        const ctrlValue = new FormControl(moment()).value; //Initialize moment when clicked
        ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
        this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    }

    chosenMonthHandler(normlizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
        const ctrlValue = new FormControl(moment()).value; //Initialize moment when clicked
        ctrlValue.month(normlizedMonth.month());
        this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
        datepicker.close();
    }
```

Only modification from the docs is removing the moment() from initialization.
Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview